# How to use eloquent between a table of source, while the other table saved data is in the form of array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have 2 tables,

1- Skills
2- Candidates

So, the data in the table "Skills" was entered from the Admin Dashboard.
And the screenshot of the table is attached.
[Table of Skills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CENC.png)

User can select multiple skills via Dropdown Multi select. (Image Attached)

[Registration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITxNO.png)

So, the second table named "Candidates" will save the complete registration form data.
Due to multiple selection of skills, I make the column type of skills as "JSON". And save data->skills in the form as shown in picture.
I am saving data of skills, by using json_encode in column "skills".
[Table for candidates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipnhn.png)

Now I have to do is,
1- Update
2- And provide a complete list for selected list.

1- I need a complete method for how to update.

**Listing of All Selected Skills**
I have try for this but not working for me.

It was just showing me only one as shown in below pic.
[The Database for a registered user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rijpk.png)
[Profile view of dashboard(It's showing only one but have 2 id's.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRT6X.png)

**Controller Function for Skill Section**

public function profile_skills(){

```
    $title = "Skills & Resume Settings";

    $id = session()->get('can_id');

    $can = Candidates::find($id);

    $skills = Skill::where('skill_id', '=', $id)->get();

    $cats = Skill::all();

    $selected = Skill::where('skill_id', '=', json_decode($can->skills))->get();

    $data = compact('title', 'can', 'cats', 'selected');

    return view('Candidate.skills')->with($data);

}
```

[Blade part of the skills display table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1UYC.png)

Comment: link the skills to candidates through a pivot table since it will be a heavy duty information. having it in a json field is not practical

Comment: Store skill information in another table candidate_skills.
Create a model for the same table CandidateSkill, and add relationship one to many 
in the Candidate model for the candidate skills also add relationships in the CandidateSkill model, so you can get skill information for every candidate with eloquent.

Comment: All right thanks for your support, but though I am new at Laravel. Can anyone give me any example code? Both of the person.